# Node.js return not is a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to use a login method, but when I define and import, the browser returns not a function

`{code: -1, msg: "login is not a function", error: 500, errorMsg: "login is not a function"}`

[image]

I am a beginner, and my general logic is to call login from the first piece of code. The login is written in the second section of code, and then the second section will call the function of the third section of SQL

```
    const express = require('express')
    const Result=require('../models/Result')
    const login=require('../services/user')
    // const debug = require('../utils/constant').debug
    const router = express.Router()

    router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
      console.log('/user/login', req.body)
      // debug && console.log(sql);
      const {username,password}=req.body
      login(username,password).then(user=>{
        if(!user||user.length ===0){
          new Result('登陆成功').success(res)
        }else{
          new Result('登陆失败').fail(res)
        }
      })

    })
    module.exports = router
```

`./services/user`

```
const {querySql}=require('../db')
return function login(username,password){
    querySql("select * from admin_user where username='${username}' and password='${password}'").then(results =>{
    }).catch(err =>{
      console.log(err);   
    })
}
module.exports={

}
```

and `./db/index.js`

```
const mysql =require('mysql')
const config =require('./config')
function connect() {
    return mysql.createConnection({
      host:config.host,
      user:config.user,
      password:config.password,
      database:config.database,
      multipleStatements: true
    })
  }

function querySql(sql){
  const conn =connect()
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    try{
      conn.query(sql,(err,results) => {
        if(err){
          reject(err)
        }else{
          resolve(results)
        }
      })
    }catch(e){
      reject(e)
    }finally{
      conn.end()
    }
  })
}
module.exports={
  connect,
  querySql
}
```

new err

```
  querySql("select * from admin_user'")
  ^

TypeError: querySql is not a function
    at login (/Users/dujinyang/admin-imooc-node/services/user.js:3:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dujinyang/admin-imooc-node/services/user.js:7:17)
```

and new querySql

```
const mysql =require('mysql')
const config =require('./config')
function connect() {
    return mysql.createConnection({
      host:config.host,
      user:config.user,
      password:config.password,
      database:config.database,
      multipleStatements: true
    })
  }

function querySql(sql){
  const conn =connect()
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    try{
      conn.query(sql,(err,results) => {
        if(err){
          reject(err)
        }else{
          resolve(results)
        }
      })
    }catch(e){
      reject(e)
    }finally{
      conn.end()
    }
  })
}
exports.querySql = querySql();
```

Comment: `return function login(username,password){` <-- should be exported not returned

Comment: syntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)

Comment: it looks like not work

Comment: `module.exports={ <-- you have it already defined.....

Comment: Hey, your code is **wide open** to SQL injection attacks... use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: I have modified my question, can you please help me look at the problem. Thank you very much. My editing mistake was very difficult. I'm sorry.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Functions in NodeJS are exported, not returned.

```
function login(username,password){
     querySql(`select * from admin_user where username=${username} and password=${password}`)
          .then(results =>{})
          .catch(err =>{ console.log(err); })
 }

exports.login = login();
```

Then

```
const {login} = require('../services/user');
```

Comment: you have a typo

Comment: thank you very much,but it have new question i will show it

Comment: Without backticks, the string interpolation isn't going to work... but you shouldn't do it this way anyway, as this method is subject to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: thank you ,i wiil explore this question,i just follow a video to study node.js,I have n’t finished it yet, maybe he will change the code, but I have to stop when I encounter a problem

Comment: I have modified my question, can you please help me look at the problem. Thank you very much. My editing mistake was very difficult. I'm sorry.

Comment: In the first block of code login needs to be in curly braces `const {login}=require('../services/user');` In the second block of code you need to import querySql from ../db/index.js `const {querySql}=require('../db/index.js');` Then export login `exports.login = login();`. Both `module.exports = {connect, querySql}` and `exports.connect = connect(); exports.querySql = querySql();` will export functions.